# Writing each row of csv to new csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file with 3 columns (Order Number, Date, File Name].

I need to create 1 csv file for each row, with a file name based on the [File Name] field and containing the [Order Number] and [Date] fields only, no headers.

With lots of help from some other posts on here, I have got as far as the below. The files are being created with the correct names, but I am getting both fields run together as one field

```
import csv
with open("//server2/shared/Data/TestExport.csv",'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            file_name ='{0}.csv'.format(row['FileName']) 
            with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
                   f.write(row['Order Number'])
                   
                   f.write(row['Date'])
```

I'm expect this is a fairly basic error - this is my first attempt at Python!

Comment: This is actually deceptively tricky to do as one either needs to keep multiple writers open or determine when to open the next writer in write or append mode. I'm sure there must be an existing example. I'll try to find one.

Comment: When you write something to a file, that is all that is written. If you want a space (or comma or whatever) between your order number and date, you need to write that to the file

Comment: *I am getting both fields run together as one field*. **PLEASE DO NOT USE EXCEL TO EXMINE CSV FILES**. Despite Excel presenting csv files as its own files, it has an awful support for them. Always first control with a dumb text editor, like notepad, notepad++, vi, etc. You will be able to *see* what separator is used. The harder part will be to find what separator **your** Excel installation expects. Once you know that, you can easily ask the Python csv module to use it.

Comment: Is the problem that the output file has the order number and date together without a separator? if you, you will need to include the comma as a separator yourself (with a call to `f.write`).

Comment: If you create a `csv.writer` or `csv.DictWriter` and have that write your file (instead of writing to a plain old file handle obtained through `open`), the writer will figure out the commas for you. Since you're using the plain old file handle, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: @pho ??? Where in the doc have you seen such a feature? And anyway, both `csv.writer` and `csv.DictWriter` take a *file like object* in their contructor and not a file name...

Comment: I never said that either takes a file name. It's well known that objects of those classes take a dictionary or list representing a row and write the correct format (separators and quote characters included) to the file @SergeBallesta

Comment: Thanks all - manually adding the comma in has got me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code is that you're using `f.write` without any delimiting, which is the core of CSV: comma-separated values.

To solve your problem, you can use a `csv.writer` and its method `writerow`:

```py
with open('//server2/shared/Data/TestExport.csv') as in_f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_f)
    for row in reader:
        file_name = '{0}.csv'.format(row['FileName'])

        # `newline=''` required for `csv.writer`
        with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as out_f:
            # Choose a delimiter to be used between the columns
            writer = csv.writer(out_f, delimiter=',')

            writer.writerow([row['Order Number'], row['Date']])
```

Your problem is solved. However, if there's two rows with the same file name, the older row's information will be overwritten with the newest rows. To solve this, you can use a dictionary to keep track of how many files are opened (i.e. do not close a file after writing to it) and use a [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) context manager to close them all:

```py
import csv
import contextlib

with open("//server2/shared/Data/TestExport.csv",'r') as in_f:
    writers = {}  # A dict[str, csv.writer] that will reuse
                  # each writer inside your file

    # Can store multiple open files
    # Will close them on the end of the `with`-block
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        reader = csv.DictReader(in_f)
        for row in reader:
            file_name ='{0}.csv'.format(row['FileName'])

            # Get the current writer for this filename
            writer = writers.get(file_name)
            
            # If there is no current writer
            if writer is None:
                # Create a new file for it
                out_f = stack.enter_context(open(file_name, 'w', newline=''))

                # `dict.setdefault` won't work here because more
                # logic is needed if the file isn't already open
                writer = csv.writer(out_f)
                writers[file_name] = writer
                # Optionally write a header on your file's first access
                writer.writerow(['OrderNumber', 'Date'])

            writer.writerow([row['Order Number'], row['Date']])
```

Comment: @pho Thank you on your excellent advice! Can you check my updated answer out?